# Is it possible to set all text in a div to the h1 style in without an h1 tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a div which contains the page's title. Is it possible to set all text to the h1 style without using tags?

For example:

```
<div id="title-div" style="h1">My Title</div>
```

Or maybe something like:

```
#title-div {
   style: h1; //Imports all styles from h1
}
```

Is this kind of thing possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Extensions to CSS such as SASS tend to have features like [@mixin](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin) which can define a set of rules once and then apply them in different places but:

- CSS itself has nothing like that
- The styles have to be explicitly defined as a mixin

Answer (score 0):

Find the css for your h1 tag and just add your div id (assuming you have control over that css and its not coming in from a 3rd party, in which case you will likely just have to copy it)

```
h1, #title-div {
    // styles
}
```

Comment: Why downvote this?  That's really the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use class or id to style your page's title.
CSS example for styling with "id":

```
                 #title-div {
                     //add your styling here
                 }
```

The other option is a "class", so in the "div" open tag, you should have "class" HML example:

```
                 <div class="title">
                 <h1>My Title</h1>
                 </div>
```

CSS example for class styling:

```
                .title {
                   //add your styling here
                }
```

Also, I think you should add in the div container h1 to understand and clear it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the default style of h1

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
line-height: 1.5;
color: #000!important;
box-sizing: inherit;
font-family: "Segoe UI",Arial,sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
margin: 10px 0;
font-size: 42px;
```